# Very slow boot time 5+ mins

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

It takes more than 5 mins to boot and I suspect it is due to a service but I cant figure out what it is really.

Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) with openmediavault 6

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.310s (kernel) + 5min 57.389s (userspace) = 5min 59.699s
graphical.target reached after 5min 56.913s in userspace
```

I ran a systemd-analyze blame

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ systemd-analyze blame
5min 37.852s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4E23\x2dEF77.service
     21.786s folder2ram_startup.service
     11.549s docker.service
      8.035s hciuart.service
      4.106s lvm2-monitor.service
      3.830s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
      3.130s containerd.service
      2.808s rpi-eeprom-update.service
      2.472s nmbd.service
      2.434s php7.4-fpm.service
      2.407s udisks2.service
      2.129s dev-mmcblk0p2.device
      2.101s systemd-random-seed.service
      1.891s nginx.service
      1.698s openmediavault-engined.service
      1.521s raspi-config.service
      1.142s srv-dev\x2ddisk\x2dby\x2duuid\x2d4E23\x2dEF77.mount
      1.072s ssh.service
       963ms systemd-logind.service
       892ms smbd.service
       882ms dphys-swapfile.service
       851ms chrony.service
       835ms systemd-resolved.service
       819ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       809ms user@1000.service
       694ms loadcpufreq.service
       584ms monit.service
       579ms networking.service
       567ms e2scrub_reap.service
       547ms rrdcached.service
       519ms keyboard-setup.service
       502ms smartmontools.service
       495ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       488ms systemd-journald.service
       423ms openmediavault-beep-up.service
       407ms systemd-udevd.service
       403ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-f3faab73\x2d01.service
       390ms rng-tools-debian.service
       383ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       380ms phpsessionclean.service
       326ms systemd-modules-load.service
       324ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
       321ms dev-mqueue.mount
       315ms run-rpc_pipefs.mount
       314ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       312ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       303ms fake-hwclock.service
       284ms collectd.service
       282ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       281ms systemd-networkd.service
       281ms polkit.service
       264ms modprobe@configfs.service
       262ms modprobe@drm.service
       258ms modprobe@fuse.service
       242ms systemd-quotacheck.service
       225ms cpufrequtils.service
       213ms alsa-restore.service
       213ms avahi-daemon.service
```

And also systemd-analyze critical chain

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @5min 56.913s
└─multi-user.target @5min 56.912s
  └─docker.service @5min 45.362s +11.549s
    └─srv-dev\x2ddisk\x2dby\x2duuid\x2d4E23\x2dEF77.mount @5min 44.126s +1.142s
      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4E23\x2dEF77.service @6.218s +5min 37.852s
        └─local-fs-pre.target @6.141s
          └─lvm2-monitor.service @2.032s +4.106s
            └─systemd-journald.socket @1.816s
              └─-.mount @964ms
                └─-.slice @963ms
```

Can anyone help me identify what is making it that slow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Notice in the `blame` output everything except `fsck` took <= ~20s.  This is the service that checks for and if possible repairs filesystem corruption before the root fs, etc., are mounted read-write.  The fact that it is taking so long implies there is some problem with your SD cards/other block storage (hard drives etc).  Either there is a very large volume of them, some drive is taking a long time to initialize (possibly due to insufficient power<sup>1</sup>), or something has physical damage that can't be repaired.  This may cause corruption that `fsck` may fix temporarily, but it shows up again later.

To isolate that, try booting with a minimum of storage (ie., just the SD card or boot device).  If the problem persists, put a fresh image on a new SD card and try that; if the problem goes away, you should replace your SD card.

If you do have a drive you don't need mounted at boot that seems to be responsible, try booting with it attached but left unmounted.  You can then run `fsck` on it manually:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1 
               ^^^^
```

I've indicated the partition dev name there to indicate this isn't the entire physical device (`/dev/sda`), it's the first filesystem on it (if there is more than one, do them all, although I believe `fsck` probably parallelizes this at boot, the low level reading can't be).

This will give you a clear indication if there are any serious insurmountable problems, and the time the check takes (errors or not).

---

1. Evidence of this should be easy to find in the system logs.  Have a look through `dmesg` right after boot.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try it out.

Comment: I tried booting without the hard drive (2 TB) and it booted in 1 min & 45 seconds. Should a filesystem check take that long for a 2tb hard drive or could there be some corruption on the hard drive? still checking dmesg tho

Comment: If `fsck` finds problems, this should be reported in the logs too.  An issue is that big drives connected via USB probably don't run at their optimal speed on a Pi.   I don't know what approximate percentage of the total volume of filesystem data `fsck` needs to look at for a default check (it is not 100%).  At 50 MB/s read, it takes 5 minutes to read 15 GB.  So this is a possibility.   Try umounting the drive and checking it manually (I've added a paragraph above about that).

Comment: Thanks a lot again! I will try doing that. Much appreciated!

Comment: root@raspberrypi4:/home/pi# sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
/dev/sda1: 4 files, 4/403266 clusters

Comment: Gives this out in less than a second. I dont know what's wrong really.

Comment: root@raspberrypi4:/home/pi# fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
exfatfsck 1.3.0
Checking file system on /dev/sda2.
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                1863 GB
Used space                 1459 GB
Available space             404 GB

That's for sda2 too

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't do much, I think, unless the fs was not properly unmounted, although you might be able to force it with `-f`.  If it does have to do stuff, the amount of time it takes can very wildly; I've seen it go on for a long time even on a small fs particularly if in the end it can't fix everything. Also: I've been assuming the filesystems are ext4 it is using the `fat` and `exfat` versions which probably doesn't speed things up.  It also says "not unmounted cleanly", implying you pulled the plug.  If you are sure that isn't the case it doesn't bode well...

Comment: ok what do you suggest then? I really dont want to format it :D

Comment: I'd disable the check (I don't know how truly repairable FAT storage is anyway).  Have a look in `/etc/fstab` and find the listings for those partitions.  There are two numbers at the end of the line, change them both to zero.   According to `man systemd-fsck` it [does respect that](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html).  Hopefully there is nothing that complicates that.

Comment: Thanks! I will try doing that hopefully this doesn't ruin anything with OMV.